# Appending new lists to dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries, `list_of_data`, which I want to update with a new entry, `formula`:

```
import itertools

list_of_data = [{'a':array([1,2]),  'b':array([3,4]) ,  'c':array([5,6])  }, 
                {'a':array([7,8]),  'b': array([9,10]), 'c':array([1,2])  },
                {'a':array([-1,4]), 'b': array([1,10]), 'c':array([4,5])  }]
#seperate keys with corresponding values
list_of_a=[]
list_of_b=[]
list_of_c=[]       

for item in list_of_data:
    for key, value in item.iteritems():
        if key =='a':
            list_of_a.append(value.tolist())
        elif key =='b':
            list_of_b.append(value.tolist()) 
        elif key == 'c':
            list_of_c.append(value.tolist())

formula=[]
for i,val in enumerate(list_of_a):

    la=list_of_a[i]
    lb=list_of_b[i]
    lc=list_of_c[i]

    for a,b,c in itertools.izip(la, lb, lc):
        formula.append((a**2)+2*b*c))

for k in range(len(list_of_data)):
    result = {'formula':formula[k]}
    list_of_data[k].update(result)
```

What I get for **Output** is:

`formula =[31, 52, 67, 104, 9,116]`

```
list_of_data = [{'a':array([1,2]),  'b':array([3,4]) ,  'c':array([5,6]), 'formula': 31 }, 
                {'a':array([7,8]),  'b': array([9,10]), 'c':array([1,2]), 'formula': 52 },
                {'a':array([-1,4]), 'b': array([1,10]), 'c':array([4,5]), 'formula': 67 }]
```

What I want to get:

```
formula =[[31, 52], [67, 104], [9,116]]

list_of_data = [{'a':array([1,2]),  'b':array([3,4]) ,  'c':array([5,6]), 'formula': array([31, 52])}, 
                {'a':array([7,8]),  'b': array([9,10]), 'c':array([1,2]), 'formula': array([67, 104])},
                {'a':array([-1,4]), 'b': array([1,10]), 'c':array([4,5]), 'formula': array([9, 116])}]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `ValueError: math domain error` suggests that `a` is negative.

Comment: but the real lists what i have contains more negative numbers :(

Comment: For interested parties:  now I've got the solution as following:

   **n = len(list_of_c)

    formula=[[]*n for x in xrange(n)]
    for i,val in enumerate(list_of_a):
        la=list_of_a[i]
        lb=list_of_b[i]
        lc=list_of_c[i]
    
        for a,b,c in itertools.izip(la, lb, lc):
             formula[i].append(((a**2)+2*b*c))**

Answer (score 1):

For interested parties:  now I've got the solution as following:

```
n = len(list_of_c)

formula=[[]*n for x in xrange(n)]
for i,val in enumerate(list_of_a):
    la=list_of_a[i]
    lb=list_of_b[i]
    lc=list_of_c[i]

    for a,b,c in itertools.izip(la, lb, lc):
         formula[i].append(((a**2)+2*b*c))
```

Answer (score -1):

SO when ValueError exception raised.

=== Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

look into your data value in loop.

Comment: the loop is not the problem, the lists what i have contains more negative numbers...